# Почему пишется, что цикл for..in плох для переборки массивов?

Tags: javascript, массивы, циклы, объекты

На [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#:%7E:text=%D0%A6%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%C2%A0for...in%C2%A0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B5) пишется, что `for..in` плох для перебора массивов т.к. перебирает их в произвольном порядке, а для массивов важен порядок...

> Цикл `for...in` проходит по свойствам в произвольном порядке.

Но также я увидел что это по этому поводу пишет [learn.javascript](https://learn.javascript.ru/object-for-in#:%7E:text=%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%2C%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE,%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%85%20%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%20%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8.):

> Соглашение говорит, что если имя свойства – нечисловая строка, то
> такие ключи всегда перебираются в том же порядке, в каком
> присваивались. С другой стороны, **если имя свойства – число или
> числовая строка, то все современные браузеры сортируют такие свойства
> в целях внутренней оптимизации.**

Получается, что все числа, которые выступают в качестве ключей, `for..in` сортирует в порядке возрастания. Св-ва с нечисловыми строками будут перебраны в порядке добавления объект. Например:

```js
//ключ-число
let objNum = {
  4: 'e',
  1: 'b',
  3: 'd',
  0: 'a',
  2: 'c'
};
for(let key in objNum) {
  console.log(key); //0, 1, 2, 3, 4
};

//ключ-строка
let objStr = {
  d: 'fourth',
  a: 'first',
  b: 'second',
  c: 'third'
};
for(let key in objStr) {
  console.log(key); //d, a, b, c
};
```

Почему тогда говорится, что цикл `for..in` перебирает св-ва в произвольном порядке?

Comment: `a=[];a.oops=1;for(k in a)console.log(k)` выведет `oops`. Обычно при переборе массивов хотят только числовые ключи.

Comment: Или в случае «разреженного» массива тоже может быть нежданчик `a=[];a[10]=1;for(k in a)console.log(k)` → только `10`

Comment: @Alexey Ten так а во втором случае что неправильно работает? Выводит ключ 10. Других же св-в там нет. Или вы имеете в виду, что должно быть `undefined` как `for..of`?

Comment: @Alexey Ten вообщем я так понял, что дело не в произвольном порядке, а вообще в некорректной работе с массивами

Comment: Не то что бы это совсем некорректно, просто в 99.99% случаев обычно при работе с массивом хотят не этого, а простого перебора всех ключей от 0 до length-1 без пропусков и лишних ненатуральных ключей.